# Nontrivial linear combinations of polynomial shifts do not cancel

Tags: polynomials

I have a proof of the following statement:

> Let $P \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ be a polynomial of degree $d\geq 1$, and $\alpha_0, \alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k \in \mathbb{Z}$, where $k\le d$. 
>   If $\sum_{i=0}^k \alpha_i \cdot P(x+i) = 0$, then all the $\alpha_i$'s are zero.

Our proof relies on a technical but easy rewriting, followed by an application of the rank theorem for Vandermonde matrices.  I feel that an easier or known proof should be around.  Any help?

Comment: Suppose $P(x)=x$, $a_0=1,a_1=-2,a_2=1$.  Then we have $x-2(x+1)+(x+2)=0$, or am I misreading something?

Comment: Did you possibly mean to connect $k$ to the degree of the polynomial or something like that?

Comment: @lulu I did.  Well, as there is an answer now, I will repost that question with the fix.

Comment: Editing the current question (as I just did for you) is better than making a new post with the correction.

Comment: Thanks @DavidC.Ullrich, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly false. For example if $P(x)=x$ then $-P(x-1)+2P(x)-P(x+1)=0$.

In fact for any $P$ of degree $d$ there is clearly a counterexample with $k=d+2$, since each $P(x-i)$ has degree $d$ and the space of all polynomials of degree no larger than $d$ has dimension $d+1<k$. (Hmm. Considering $\Bbb Q[x]$ we get rational $\alpha_i$,  hence we can get integral $\alpha_i$.)

Comment: Thanks, very appreciated; I forgot indeed to indicate $k \leq d$, my bad.